# Using a trained Neural Network to classify new data

Tags: matlab

Am trying to use a trained neural network to classify new vehicles in Matlab. Each vehicle object has four features (4-D feature space). There are 3 classes of vehicles: small, medium and large. When I use a new input,the  network returns a 3x4 matrix. How do I obtain the predicted class from this matrix? 
I used the following:

```
newprediction = sim(net,XM38)
```

The output is:

```
newprediction =

0.0018    0.9915    0.9938    0.0018
0.0694    0.0085    0.0062    0.0694
0.9287    0.0001    0.0000    0.9287
```

How do I interpret these results and so obtain the predicted class?

Comment: The output of the NN has been defined by you (or by whoever trained it). You have decided what it should output, so, you should be the one knowing how to interpret it! If I would train a NN to identify 3 objects, my NN would have 3 outputs.

Comment: I'm assuming you gave your network 4 cases / records to try classify? Normally the output would be what you have but transposed but in your case it looks like each class is represented by a row and each instance by a column. Classifying an instance is just a matter of choosing which class showed the highest probability. In your case nothing is ambiguous, each column has one row that is almost one while the rest are almost zero.

Comment: Say each row represents a class. So I compute magnitude of the row and choose the highest?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your output is a prediction for each vehicle of it belonging to each class expressed as a percentage [0,1]. If this is the case the classification should be the class with the highest probability.

However, you should check how you defined the output of the network to double check.